# How to connect to Azure SQL database from Django app on Linux VM

Tags: python, sql-server, django, azure-sql-database, freetds

I searched tutorials or full explanations about using SQL Azure Database with Django application, that hosted on Linux VM.

I changed database section of settings.py like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'azure_database_name',
        'USER': 'user@server_name_like_wjrnvlwjrng3',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_pass',
        'HOST': 'server_name_like_wjrnvlwjrng3.database.windows.net',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'FreeTDS',
            'TDS_Version': '7.1',
        }
    }
}
```

I append

```
[MyDb]
    host = server_name_like_wjrnvlwjrng3.database.windows.net
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.1
```

to /etc/freetds/freetds.conf

And changed /etc/odbc.ini

```
[MyDb]
Description     = ololo lalala text
Driver          = FreeTDS
Servername      = server_name_like_wjrnvlwjrng3
Database        = azure_database_name
UID             = user@server_name_like_wjrnvlwjrng3
PWD             = my_pass
Port            = 1433
Charset         = UTF-8
```

And after that I tried to call `python manage.py migrate` and got an error

```
django.db.utils.Error: ('001', '[001] [nxDC[reD]SLSre]nbet onc odt ore (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Please, help me with it.

Comment: SQL Azure is not officially supported by Django. There is an ADO based adapter for MS SQL, but that runs on Windows only.

Comment: @KlausD. Oh... Thanks, new question =)
Does exist way to use Azure databases instead of deploy MySQL (or others) on a VM?

Comment: In general you will be very happy with one of the officially supported databases. The DB with third-party support can make you happy (or not) and everything else does not work. Details at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a way to connect to your SQL Azure database in Python and Django using pymssql and FreeTDS on a Linux machine.
Here is how you can do it :
In the terminal, navigate to the directory where your manage.py is located. 
Install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install freetds-dev freetds-bin
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-pip
sudo pip pymssql
```

You are essentially installing FreeTDS and Pymssql in your environment. This will allow you to connect to your SQL Database. What you are trying to do is use pyodbc natively with Django on a linux machine to access your SQL Azure database which is not possible currently.

Once you have the packages are installed you can use the following python code to create a table, insert/update a row and select all the contents. For simplicity/testing you can place the code in your views.py script. Make sure you have a database created in which you would like to create your table, otherwise it will select the default

```
# Connect
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(server='test.database.windows.net', user='newuser@test', password='yourpassword', database='sampledatabase')
cursor = conn.cursor()

#Create
cursor.execute("""
IF OBJECT_ID('votes', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE votes
CREATE TABLE votes (
    name VARCHAR(100),
    value INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(name)
)
""")

#Insert
cursor.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO votes VALUES (%s, %d)",
    [('NodeJS', '0'),
     ('Python', '0'),
     ('C#', '0')])
# you must call commit() to persist your data if you don't set autocommit to True
conn.commit()

        #Select
 cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM votes')
     result = ""
     row = cursor.fetchone()
     while row:
         result += str(row[0]) + str(" : ") + str(row[1]) + str(" votes")
         result += str("\n")
         row = cursor.fetchone()
     print result
```

We just created a table called votes, inserted values inside it and used a select statement to print all the contents. Hope this helps. If you still need help, don’t hesitate to reach out. I have a walk through guide that might help you if need be.

Comment: Thanks, I think about local MySQL db on the same VM and configure it to master-master replication now