# Troubles of making Django Models work on MS-SQL on MS Azure?

Tags: python, sql-server, django, azure, model

I want to create a django web on Azure.

I spent all day on trying to connect my model classes to an exist MSSQL database on Azure.

It still did not work. My hand is tried.

I list my steps, and hope someone to help me thanks a lot!

Step1. Install dependency libraries

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
sudo pip install django-pyodbc
sudo pip install django-sqlserver
sudo pip install django-mssql
sudo pip install django-pyodbc-azure
brew install freetds
brew install freetds --with-unixodbc
```

Step2. Configuration writing

```
~/.bash_profile
    #ODBC
    export ODBCSYSINI=/usr/local/opt/unixodbc/etc
    export ODBCINI=/usr/local/opt/unixodbc/etc/odbc.ini

/etc/odbcinst.ini
    [FreeTDS]
    Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
    Setup=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
    Server={host}
    UsageCount=1
    Port=1433
    Database={db name}
    User={user name}
    Password={password}
    TDS_Version=7.2
    client_charset=utf-8

/etc/odbc.ini
    [FreeTDS]
    Driver = FreeTDS
    ServerName = {hostname}
    Database = {db name}
    UserName = {user name}
    Password = {password}
    Port = 1433
    Protocol = 7.2
    TDS_Version = 8.0
```

Step3. Try to connect DB.

```
tsql -S FreeTDS -p 1433 -U {user name} -P {password}

It’s ok to connect to ‘INFORMATION_SCHEMA’ DB。

But when I try:

    tsql -S FreeTDS -p 1433 -U {user name} -P {password} -D {database name}

I had problems:

    Msg 4075 (severity 16, state 1) from {hostname} Line 1:
        "The USE database statement failed because the database collation Chinese_Traditional_Stroke_Order_100_CS_AS_WS is not recognized by older client drivers. Try upgrading the client operating system or applying a service update to the database client software, or use a different collation. See SQL Server Books Online for more information on changing collations."
    Msg 18456 (severity 14, state 1) from {hostname} Line 1:
        "Login failed for user ‘{user name}’.”
    Error 20002 (severity 9):
        Adaptive Server connection failed
    There was a problem connecting to the server

If I try “tsql -S FreeTDS -p 1433 -U {user name} -P {password}” and under,

1> USE somedb
2> go
    Msg 40508 (severity 16, state 1) from {hostname} Line 1:
        "USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database."

problems again. (I found some pages to says: USE is not work at a MSSQL DB on Azure)
```

Step4. Try: python manage.py inspectdb > models.py

```
django.db.utils.Error: ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Step5. Try models

```
settings.py
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
            'NAME': ‘{database name}’,
            'USER': ‘{user name}’,
            'PASSWORD': ‘{password}’,
            'HOST': ‘{hostname}’,
            'PORT': '1433',
            'OPTIONS': {
                'driver': 'FreeTDS',
            },
        }
    }

and

$python manage.py shell

>>> from app.models import {ModelName}
>>> {ModelName}.objects.all()

    Error: ('08001', '[08001] [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

(again, no surprise.)
```

Environments:

1. Python: 2.7.10
2. Django: 1.9.4 (final)
3. MS-SQL Server Version: V12
4. OS: Mac OSX 10.11.3
5. FreeTDS: 0.95.80
6. Others

   ```
   pyobjc-core (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-Accounts (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-AddressBook (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-Automator (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-Cocoa (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-Collaboration (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-CoreData (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-CoreText (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-EventKit (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-FSEvents (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-Message (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-PubSub (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-QTKit (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-Quartz (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-SearchKit (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-Social (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-SyncServices (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration (2.5.1)
   pyobjc-framework-WebKit (2.5.1)
   pyodbc (3.0.10)
   django-mssql (1.6.2)
   django-pyodbc-azure (1.9.3.0)
   django-sqlserver (1.7)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, it seems that you need to configure the Driver `/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so` of FreeTDS in the `odbc.ini` file on your Mac OS.

There is [a similiar answered thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571568/how-to-connect-to-azure-sql-database-from-django-app-on-linux-vm) you can refer to that suggest to use `pymssql` package to connect Azure SQL Database. Also, you can see the Azure offical doc [Connect to SQL Database by using Python on Ubuntu Linux](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-python-simple-ubuntu-linux/).

Comment: I tried it, and didn't work. And my environment is Mac OSX.

Comment: @wuufone In most scenarios, the usage of MacOSX is similiar with Linux's. Sorry for not reproducing your issue without Mac environment, but I suggest that you can try to search the configuration for Linux with Search Engine and refer to the related articles to re-configure it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "adaptive server" error.

I solved with the option "host_is_server" in the "OPTIONS" section of the django db configuration:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxx',
        'HOST': 'host',
        'PORT': '1433',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'FreeTDS',
            'host_is_server': True,
        },
    }
}
```